# Ошибка при чтении файла

Tags: c++builder, файлы

пытаюсь прочитать файл таким образом:

```
 #pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^     e) {
TStringList* sl;
TStringList* sl= new TStringList();
    sl->LoadFromFile("C:\\333.txt");

         }
};
}
```

выдаёт ошибки:

```
error C2065: 'TStringList' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'sl' : undeclared identifier
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'TStringList'
error C2227: left of '->LoadFromFile' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Comment: `TStringList`? Вы случайно с Delphi не перепутали?

(И кстати, рекомендую сдать в макулатуру C++/CLI и писать либо на чистом C++, либо на чистом C#.)

Comment: @VladD это похоже на c++ builder.  
@Никола Кривошея модуль classes подключен?

Comment: @Yura: меня запутали `System::Void` и `System::EventArgs^`, я думал, это только в C++/CLI. Но это же не чистый C++, а нечто, основанное а .NET, да?

Comment: @VladD, нет это VCL. т.е. то же самое что в Delphi, только на плюсах.